# Does the annotation of @XmlRootElement in JAXB have to add Java class in any case?

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

Does the annotation of @XmlRootElement in JAXB have to add Java class in any case?

I want not to add any annotations in Java class.

Please tell me any solutions if any.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use the @XmlRootElement annotation.  Instead you can wrap your root object in an instance of JAXBElement:

```
QName qName = new QName(null, "customer");
JAXBElement<Customer> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Customer>(qName, Customer.class, customer);
marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
```

For a more detailed example see:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

JAXB Implementations such as [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead) also offer alternate metadata representations such as XML.  For an example check out:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: Thank you Blaise! But this example is a marshaling case, how about the unmarshaling case ? I think unmarshaling does not apply JAXBElement as an argument, so is @XmlRootElement annotation indispensable?

Comment: You can specify the type you wish to unmarshal by specifying the class as a parameter on some unmarshal methods.  This will return the result wrapped in a JAXBElement.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, Blaise. I overlooked some unmarshal methods... I tried again, it successed! Thank you! And I hava one more related question. Now I create JAXBContext and (Marshaller or Unmarshaller) instances whenever accessing to the server, because JAXBContext does not apply the same arguments but different classes. Is there any problems in the performance ?

Comment: JAXBContext is a thread safe object and it is best if you can create it once and reuse it rather than constantly recreating it as there is some cost in initializing it.  Marshaller and Unmarshaller are not thread safe and have a small cost to instantiate so you will want to create a new instance per operation.